# How to use command prompts to compile code?

Tags: c#

Alright, I've been spoiled enough already by IDEs, and I want to learn how to use the prompt to compile code.

Where can I find good learning material, me being completely oblivious to the matter? To be more specific, I'd like to know how to use C#'s csc.exe fully, though I hope that the knowledge will be appliable to other compilers as well.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most compilers (as well other command line tools) provide help by using "/?" option - read it and in most cases it is enough to get simple code compiled.

For more real cases use project files

- *.csproj for C#/ *.vbproj for VB.Net , use MSBuild to build. You already have them if you ever created project in VS.
- makefiles for many other compilers